# Convert matrix elements to float in python

Tags: python-3.x

So, here is the thing, I have the following matrix:

```
a = np.array([["1","2","3","4"],
              ["5","6","7","8"]])
```

as you can see the values are strings and I want the the matrix to be like follows:

```
a = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0],
              [5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]])
```

the previous matrices are examples, the main idea is convert strings which inner concept values are numbers. Direct convertion won't work:

```
a = [float(i) for i in a ] #not working
```

or:

```
a = [float(i) for i in j for j in a ] #not working either
```

I found similar questions with cero responses, or with not working answers, please keep in mind that I am beginner, please be kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use astype function of numpy arrays as follows:

```
a = a.astype(float)
```

Comment: Amazing! It works flawlessly, thank you so much for your answer, I don't have the level to vote, nevertheless that's the correct answer.